# установка psycorg2 на сервере UBUNTU 18.04 (команда pip3 install psycorg2)

Tags: python-3.x, linux, ubuntu

пытаюсь установить указанный пакет , получаю ошибки:
куда он меня посылает, в какую сторону копать, кто подскажет? (интернет есть, но по указанной в конце ссылке я и правда не могу перейти с ошибкой 404)

Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 353, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 795, in get_page
    resp.raise_for_status()

  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/models.py", line 935, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)

requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/psycorg2/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы опечатались:

```py
Неверно: psycorg2
Верно:   psycopg2
              ^
```

Попробуйте так:

```py
pip3 install psycopg2
```

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!

Comment: @andrnosenko Рад помочь :) Если ответ помог Вам, то Вы можете отметить его как верный, нажав на зелёную галочку слева.